# Java Implements interface

Tags: java, interface, implements

this is my attempt at implementing an interface.

im getting the following error

```
javac MyCollection.java
./au/edu/uow/Collection/DVDAlbum.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Album
public class DVDAlbum implements Album{
```

this is the super class

```
package au.edu.uow.Collection;


public interface Album {

    String getMediaType();

    String getTitle();

    String getGenre();

}
```

And this is the sub class

```
public class DVDAlbum implements Album{

    private String Title;
    private String Genre;
    private String Director;
    private String Plot;
    private String MediaType;

    public DVDAlbum(String TempTitle, String TempGenre, String TempDirector, String TempPlot){
        Title = TempTitle;
        Genre = TempGenre;
        Director = TempDirector;
        Plot = TempPlot;
    }
    String getMediaType(){
        return MediaType;
    }
    String getTitle(){
        return Title;
    }
    String getGenre(){
        return Genre;
    }
}
```

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-abstract-class-and-interface
This was the reference i used but its not working for me.

Comment: Are you importing the interface?

Comment: They're probably in separate packages so you have to use `import  au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;` in the file containing `DVDAlbum`. BTW, package names should be written in lowercase.

Comment: check your main class MyCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't in the same package where the interface is declared, you need to import it:

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;
```

Or use the complete qualified name:

```
public class DVDAlbum implements au.edu.uow.Collection.Album{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;

public class DVDAlbum implements Album{
    //....
}
```

and

```
import au.edu.uow.Collection.DVDAlbum;
import au.edu.uow.Collection.Album;

public class MyCollection {
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your interface  package is correctly imported.

Comment: if the interface is called Album.java would the import statement be Import Album.java ??

Comment: Album.java is the file name, not the interface name. You can't use dots in Java class names.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
./au/edu/uow/Collection/DVDAlbum.java:6: cannot find symbol
```

means, that `DVDAlbum` and `Album` are *intended* to be in the same package and therefore no `import` is necessary.

BUT: The `DVDAlbum` is NOT in the right package because the `package` line is missing. So just copy the `package` line from `Album` into `DVDAlbum` .